# Create an image out of a virtualbox installation

Tags: virtualbox

I'm planning to shift to Arch Linux, but before I do that I would want to experiment on it first inside Virtualbox. When I am done baking and tweaking it I would want to create an image out of it and install it on a dedicated machine, so that I would not run into setting it up again from scratch. Is there a way to do that in Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same as with two real machines, for example:

- Booting the "source" machine with Clonezilla or Parted Magic or any Live CD
- Clone the system to a network share (NFS, SAMBA, SSH server...), outside of the "source" machine obviously
- Boot the "destination" machine with any of the mentioned Live CDs, and restore the clone from the network share

Comment: Linux isnt my "thing" but be sure to include/compile in any hardware drivers you might need to allow it to boot.  For example, I have had some issues with Linux not recognizing my SATA controller by default.